# How to send an Email confirmation after contact us

Tags: magento2, email, contact-form

When the client uses the contact form, how can I get a confirmation email to the user?

Comment: He made it clear `confirmation email to the user` not for himself ! there no configuration for that

Answer (score 1):

I think your need to send some **Email confirmation** to the user when he/she send a contact form !

Lest's go,  we will use an **observer** for that with `controller_action_postdispatch_contact_index_post` as **event**.

In your module you have to add these **4 files**, you replace `{Vendor}/{Module}` with you vendor, module name.

`app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Observer/SendContactConfirmationEmail.php`

`app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/events.xml`

`app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/email_templates.xml`

`app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/email/email_template.html`

**A Content :**

`app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Observer/SendContactConfirmationEmail.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Class SendContactConfirmationEmail
 * @object Send an email confirmation to the user after submi a contact form
 * @autor @mir
 */

namespace {Vendor}\{Modulename}\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SendContactConfirmationEmail implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $_request;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * For logger, var/log
     */
    protected $_logger;



    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }


    public function execute(EventObserver  $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $name = $event->getRequest()->getPost()['name'];
        $email = $event->getRequest()->getPost()['email'];
        $content = $event->getRequest()->getPost()['comment'];

        if ($email) {
            try {
                $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
                $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('contact_confirmation_template')
                    ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
                    ->setTemplateVars(
                        [
                            'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(),
                            'name' => $name,
                            'email' => $email,
                            'content' => $content,
                        ]
                    )
                    ->setFrom('general') //Store -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses
                    ->addTo($email, $name)
                    ->getTransport();
                $transport->sendMessage();
                //$this->_logger->info("Message sent !");
                return;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->_logger->critical($e->getMessage());
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_postdispatch_contact_index_post">
        <observer name="sendEmailCustomerContactConfirmation" instance="\Sd\Sdsolutions\Observer\SendContactConfirmationEmail" />
    </event>
</config>
```

`app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/email_templates.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:Magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="contact_confirmation_template" label="Confirmation contact email" file="email_template.html" type="html" module="Vendor_Modulename" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

`app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/email/email_template.html`

```
<!--@subject Contact Form Confirmation@-->

<p>Dear <b>{{var name}}</b>, your message has been received, we will answer you in the best time.</p>

<p>Your message:</p>
<h4>{{var content}}</h4>

<p>Regards.</p>
```

<sup>Good luck.</sup>

Comment: I'm going to test your solution, I'm with version 2.2.3 of magento. ty bro

Comment: @AlfredoLópezNunes did it work?

Comment: HI @Prince.. I tried your solution. It is sending mails but issue is the customer receives mail but also the admin/client email where the contact form data mail is send also receives thankyou mail

Comment: Sending back a copy of the comment content is really a bad idea. What is to stop anyone entering any email address in and spam content.

Answer (score 0):

1. On the Admin sidebar, tap Stores. Then under Settings, choose Configuration.
2. In the panel on the left under General, choose Contacts
3. Expand the Email Options section. Then, do the following:
4. In the Send Emails to field, enter the email address where messages from the Contact Us form are sent.
5. Set Email Sender to the store identity that appears as the sender of the message from the Contact Us form. For example: Custom Email 2.
6. Set Email Template to the template that is used for messages sent from the Contact Us form.
7. Save

Answer (score 0):

I put together a solution using plugin

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/311559/70343

Here is link to repo

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ContactResponse

It's  always safer to go plugin route as less likely to conflict with other extensions

Answer (score -1):

To get contact configuration navigate to

> Store > Configuration > General > Contacts

and set email in field `Send Emails to` where you want to get contact form email.

Check image for help -

[image]